# color bar underneath image shows up

Tags: html, css

I am trying to fill in images of non-geometric shapes from left to right according to percentage. For example, if I wanted 30% of the shapes filled in, only that percentage of the shapes would be filled in from left to right.

I can get the shapes filled in, but there's a bar of color that also appears underneath the filled shapes. How do I prevent this from showing up?

```
    <div class="pic" >
         <img class = "image" height= "100%" width = "100%"   
          src="http://i60.tinypic.com/warmo6.png"/>
    </div>


    .pic {
      background: linear-gradient(to right, red 40%, white 60%);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to you CSS:

```
.pic img { vertical-align: top; }
```

[Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/b2567gqL/)